# Rotate matplotlib pie plot label to 90 degree

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to rotate the labels to verticle (e.g. along the `y-axis`).

```
a0.pie(adata, labels=alabel,startangle=180, radius=1, autopct='%1.1f%%')
a1.pie(bdata, explode=explode, labels=blabel, startangle=0, autopct="%1.1f%%")
```

By default, it is parallel to the `x-axis`, and `rotatelabels=True` is not an option in this case, as I want, 90degree rotation.

How I can do that?

Comment: In the duplicate the rotation is a bit more involved than what it needed here, but you may just replace the angles used there with a constant `90` to have vertically oriented labels.

Comment: its not a duplicate of that, as that rotates the label incrimently, which is now taken care by rotatelabels, but I am looking for all labels rotated to 90

Comment: Exactly, so instead of the incremental step you just put `90` there.